# NullReferenceException: Tensorflow lite models in unity android builds

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, tensorflow-lite, tflite

i imported the tensorflow lite plugin into untiy, im trying  to intergrate an existing tflite model into my script but when i create the object, i get the error

"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
TensorFlowLite.Interpreter..ctor (System.Byte[] modelData, TensorFlowLite.InterpreterOptions options) (at Packages/com.github.asus4.tflite/Runtime/Interpreter.cs:73)
TensorFlowLite.Interpreter..ctor (System.Byte[] modelData) (at Packages/com.github.asus4.tflite/Runtime/Interpreter.cs:61)
ListenerController.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/ListenerController.cs:27)
"

i tried reading the model data in different ways to make sure the model was loaded in properly but that wasnt the issue, so i tried making the instance of the object in different ways, private, public and local variables.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out passing in the optional parameter for InterpreterOptions when making the object works fine.